# Split list into two lists with single LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to split a list into two lists with a single LINQ statement. I'm currently doing this:

```
var listA = allItems.Where(item => item.IsUseful);
var listB = allItems.Except(listA);
```

But I want a single LINQ statement in query syntax that iterates over the original list only once, and returns an anonymous type with the two lists as properties (eg results.ListA; results.ListB).

Comment: Need sample data, please.

Answer (score 9):

This will give you a `Dictionary<bool, List<T>>` with two lists, which you can easily get your lists with `result[true]` and `result[false]`:

```
var result = allItems.GroupBy(item => item.IsUseful)
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: Definitely the more readable solution.

Comment: Breaks if all values are the same (all true or all false). Use ToLookup.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to access it through a named property like "Results.ListA" and "Result.ListB" without using reflection which would be MUCH more costly, but this will get you pretty close by accessing by the position:

```
var results = allItems.GroupBy(item => item.IsUseful).ToList();
results.First();  // this will access listA
results.Last();   // this will access listB
```

Or in **query** syntax as that's what you stated in the question:

```
var results = (from x in allItems
               group x by x.IsUseful
               into groupings
               select groupings).ToList(); 

results.First();  // this will access listA
results.Last();   // this will access listB
```

Comment: Is there some guaranteed inherent order to the groups? (i.e. `results = {GroupTrue, GroupFalse}` where `GroupTrue` is a group containing elements which satisfied the condition `.IsUseful`).